# Prove that if $f$ has an isolated singularity at $z_0$ then the principal part of the Laurent series of $f$ at $z_0$ converges in $\mathbb C\ z_0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, laurent-series, singularity

> Prove that if a holomorphic function $f$ has an isolated singularity at $z_0$ then the principal part of the Laurent series of $f$ at $z_0$ converges in $\mathbb C\setminus \{z_0\}$

I think this ought to be connected with the Cauchy Integral formula in some way, but I'm not quite sure.

This is a duplicate of [this 4 year old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3153652/943723) which does not have any answers yet. So, I decided to ask it again.

Answer (score 0):

Assume wlog $z_0=0$ and note that $f(z)=\sum_{n >0}b_nz^{-n}+g(z)$ where $g$ is holomorphic on a disc of radius $\delta$ around $0$,  and let $h(z)=\sum_{n >0}b_nz^{-n}$.

For any $r< \delta$ let $\max_{|z|=r} |f(z)|=M_r$. Then for any $n \ge 1$ we have $$|b_n|=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}f(z)z^{n-1}dz$$ and since $|dz|=r$ we have that $|b_n| \le M_r r^n$ hence $|b_n|^{1/n} \le M_r^{1/n}r$ so $\limsup |b_n|^{1/n} \le r$

Since $r>0$ can be taken as small as we want, we get that $\limsup |b_n|^{1/n} =0$ so $h(1/z)=\sum_{n \ge 1}b_nz^n$ is entire, which means precisely that $h$ is analytic on $\mathbb C\setminus \{z_0\}$ and we are done!

Comment: $h(z)=f(z)-g(z)$ is holomorphic in a punctured disk of raidu $\delta$ around $0$, let $w=1/z$, then series $\sum_{n >0}b_nw^n$ is convergent in $\frac{1}{\delta}<|w|<\infty$. Because $\sum_{n >0}b_nw^n$ is a power series, so $\sum_{n >0}b_nw^n$ is convergent in the whole complex plane $\mathbb{C}$. This implies $\sum_{n >0}b_nz^{-n}$ is convergent in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.